# making a static bubble cloud

Tags: python, visualization

I am looking for an api or library to plot some static bubble cloud like the one [here](http://vallandingham.me/bubble_cloud/)

I know, it must be easy, since it is just some circles and their radius is based on some number; for me locating them is kind of challenging, in a way to not over lap each other. Is there any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the tutorial [here](http://vallandingham.me/building_a_bubble_cloud.html) to make your own?

Looks like it'd be pretty complete. Failing that, check out the [source code](https://github.com/vlandham/bubble_cloud)

Comment: I am looking for something static - P.S I already put this link in my question.